# How to effectively manage autostart in Linux Ubuntu/Mint (KDE)?

Tags: linux-mint, startup

I am aware I can use 'autostart' package.

However there are certain programs (e.g. 2 windows of Dolphin) which start automatically despite they're not in autostart.

Also, certain program fail to run effectively blocking others (as explained at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244462/why-does-linux-mint-17-2-ubuntu-14-04-based-kde-occasionally-fails-to-autost ).

So, how do I manage **manually** which programs should run on Linux Mint (17.2 in my case) startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ArchLinux, with KDE, there is [this way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#Autostarting_applications), or [that way.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#Autostart) I suppose it works with Mint too..
You can check in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` or `~/.config/autostart/` for example.

Comment: are those symlinks?

Comment: No, they are directories... Everything in /etc is for your system configuration, and everything in ~/.config are for your personnal configuration. If you are the only user of your system, it doesn't matter which you choose. You can access these by the terminal, and put there the desktop files of the applications you want to autostart. Read the articles on Arch wiki to learn more about that.

Comment: actually their content is different (and I'm the only user). Furthermore there are apps (e.g. Dolphin and Konsole) which run whether they're in those directories (or autostart) or not

Comment: Have you check in KDE settings, that your session is not restored when you log in ? If yes, you can tell KDE which applications you don't want to be restored, I think.

Comment: where do I actually find KDE settings?

Comment: You type Alt+F2, then "KDE settings" or just "setting" (or better, just "startup")...
And after that you learn how to use your desktop ;)

Comment: Actually I finally switched to Debian (and the issue is gone). KDE settings is not in Debian either. but thanks ;)